# remove newline characters from text file while writing data

Tags: c

I am getting a newline character into a text file while I was writing some content into the text file using the code below

```
sprintf(str,"GodownName,LorryNumber,InvoiceNumber,CementCompanyName,RcvdPrsnName,RcvdPrsNDsgnation,EntityQty,Date\0");
write(fd,str,strlen(str));
```

the text is writing from 2nd row and an unwanted newline is writing at 1st row. I want my text to be written from 1st row. So please any one help me to remove newline characters or spaces from text file

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have another function which writes in `fd` before the call of this function.

Besides, writing `"\0"` at the end of a string litteral is useless, there's already one.

Comment: Yeah i got it.. I am writing newline character into fd before this call.. thanks to make me introspect my code.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `\0` at the end. Is `str` long enough? If not that could cause the problem that you are encountering.